# Build a new subrecord in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

In case I need to build a new Subrecord include Item Sublist, does SuiteScript can do that?
Like Build a Custom Record that has a sublist, and Sublist has a Subrecord..
I just wanna ask: do customization with SuiteScript can help us to do that?

Thank you,

Ba Loc

Comment: in item sub list it is a select field right (Custom Record).

Comment: Hi  Praveen Kumar,
Yes, it is a select field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you cannot have custom Subrecord in NS.

Comment: Thank you vVinceth. 
I'll find another way else to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Solutiom
 1. Create a Transaction Line Fields
 2. Then set field type as List/Record and select that custom list
 3. Apply to particular transaction forms

Note: Navigate to Customization -> List,Record Or Fields -> Transaction Line Fields

Comment: Dear Praveen Kumar,
Thank you for provide solution.
In this case, I need to build a new Subrecord (like Landed Cost or Inventory Detail or Order Schedule) because add so many Line Field in one line is not a good ideal. Do you think it is better if create a Subrecord hold all the field with value we need to add to a line (or Sublist line)? If we use your solution, We need to add more than 50 field.

Comment: please ensure that you talk about parent child relationship right.

Comment: I would like to ask does NetSuite allows us to customize a new SubRecord? Or do we have any way to build a Subrecord with any value we want?